# Flex Builder Import Web service errors in autogen code

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, flexbuilder

I'm trying to import a web service with the Flex builder feature (Data > Import Web Service). The process proceeds as expected and the classes are generated based on the web service description. The code is generated with compile errors in it though.

There are 20 errors of 2 varieties. I've included a sample of the errors below.

It looks like an error in the auto gen. The auto gen code is trying to dispatch an object of ArrayCollection type. As far I know that isn't possible.

Does anyone have advice or has anyone had similar problems?

**Error examples:**

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type net.responsys:ListTablesForCampaignResultEvent to an unrelated type flash.events:Event.  Responsys/src/net/responsys ResponsysWS57.as

1119: Access of possibly undefined property headers through a reference with static type net.responsys:ListFolderContentsResultEvent.   Responsys/src/net/responsys ResponsysWS57.as
```

Comment: Alternatively, are their other methods of importing web services to be used in Flash / Flex?

Answer (score 0):

If they are both from an "Event" class, it might be a scoping problem.  Try qualifying all of the Event instances, e.g. look into the generated code and wherever you see a flash Event, add flash.events before it.
So a declaration of a flash event might look like:
var event:flash.events.Event

instead of

var event:Event